# how "data" and "target" are choosen in a federated learning? (PySyft)

Tags: python, pytorch, federated-learning, pysyft

i can't understand how in function train() below, the variable (data, target) are choosen.

```
def train(args, model, device, federated_train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(federated_train_loader): # <-- now it is a distributed dataset
        model.send(data.location) # <-- NEW: send the model to the right location`
```

i guess they are 2 tensor representing 2 random images of dataset train, but then the loss function

```
loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
```

is calculated at every interaction with different target?

Also i have different question: i trained the network with images of cats, then i test it with images of cars and the accuracy reached is 97%. How is this possible? is a proper value or i'm doing something wrong?

here is the entire code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

import syft as sy  # <-- NEW: import the Pysyft library
hook = sy.TorchHook(torch)  # <-- NEW: hook PyTorch ie add extra functionalities to support Federated Learning
bob = sy.VirtualWorker(hook, id="bob")  # <-- NEW: define remote worker bob
alice = sy.VirtualWorker(hook, id="alice")  # <-- NEW: and alice

class Arguments():
    def __init__(self):
        self.batch_size = 64
        self.test_batch_size = 1000
        self.epochs = 2
        self.lr = 0.01
        self.momentum = 0.5
        self.no_cuda = False
        self.seed = 1
        self.log_interval = 30
        self.save_model = False

args = Arguments()

use_cuda = not args.no_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available()

torch.manual_seed(args.seed)

device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")

kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': True} if use_cuda else {}

federated_train_loader = sy.FederatedDataLoader( # <-- this is now a FederatedDataLoader
    datasets.MNIST("C:\\users...\\train", train=True, download=True,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                       transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                   ]))
    .federate((bob, alice)), # <-- NEW: we distribute the dataset across all the workers, it's now a FederatedDataset
    batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, **kwargs)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST("C:\\Users...\\test", train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                       transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                   ])),
    batch_size=args.test_batch_size, shuffle=True, **kwargs)


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 50, 5, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4*4*50, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 4*4*50)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

def train(args, model, device, federated_train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(federated_train_loader): # <-- now it is a distributed dataset
        model.send(data.location) # <-- NEW: send the model to the right location
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        model.get() # <-- NEW: get the model back
        if batch_idx % args.log_interval == 0:
            loss = loss.get() # <-- NEW: get the loss back
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * args.batch_size, len(federated_train_loader) * args.batch_size,
                100. * batch_idx / len(federated_train_loader), loss.item()))

def test(args, model, device, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in test_loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, reduction='sum').item() # sum up batch loss
            pred = output.argmax(1, keepdim=True) # get the index of the max log-probability
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)

    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))


model = Net().to(device)
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr) # TODO momentum is not supported at the moment

for epoch in range(1, args.epochs + 1):
    train(args, model, device, federated_train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
    test(args, model, device, test_loader)

if (args.save_model):
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), "mnist_cnn.pt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider it like this. When you hook torch, all your torch tensors will get additional functionality - methods like `.send()`, `.federate()`, and attributes like `.location` and `._objects`. Your data and target, which were once torch tensors, became pointers to tensors residing in different `VirtualWorker` objects due to `.federate((bob, alice))`.

Now data and target have additional attributes that includes `.location`, which will return the location of that tensor - data/target pointed by the pointer called data/target.

Federated learning sends the global model to this location, as seen in `model.send(data.location)`.

Now, `model` is a pointer residing at the same location and `data` is also a pointer residing there. Hence when you take the output as `output = model(data)`, output will also reside there and all we (the central server or in other words, the VirtualWorker called `'me'`) will get is a pointer to that output.

Now, regarding your doubt on loss calculation, since output and target are both residing in that same location, calculation of `loss` will also happen there. Same goes for backprop and step.

Finally, you can see `model.get()`, here is where the central server pulls the remote model using the pointer called `model`. (I'm not sure if it should be `model = model.get()` though).

So anything with `.get()` will be pulled from that worker and will be returned in our python statement. Also note that `.get()` will remove that object from it's location when called. Hence use `.copy().get()` if you are going to need it further.